# Python string "in" operator

Tags: python

```
txt = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain"
x = "ain" in txt
print(x) // True

txt = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain "
x = " " in txt
print(x) // True

txt = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain "
x = " " in txt.strip()

print(x) // True ,
```

Even after removing whitespaces it is giving truthy.

Comment: this is realy true synce " " is a string and "" is a string to

Comment: `strip` doesn't remove all whitespace.  It only removes leading and trailing whitespace.  The obvious check would have been to `print(txt)` to see what you were doing.  Try it.

Comment: Well, operator `in` checks if string contains given argument and in your examples string actually does contain every arguments you check it against.

Answer (score 5):

`strip()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, not all spaces within the string.

Answer (score 3):

`txt.replace(" ", "")` this will remove all the spaces.

If you also want to remove other whitespaces,

```
txt = "".join(txt.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

strip() removes both leading and trailing characters.
Means the text would look like this

> "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain"

but there are still whitespace between words

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain "
txt.strip()
```

Output:

```
'The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain'
```

`stript()` just removes the spaces at the beginning and the end and not the spaces in betwen the string. Therefor the following statement is true:

```
x = " " in txt.strip()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
True
```

There are many ways to remove all spaces in a string:

**1. `split()`**

```
''.join(txt.split())
```

**2. `replace()`**

```
txt.replace(" ", "")
```

**3. Regular expression:**

```
import re
stringWithoutSpaces = re.sub(r"\s+", "", txt, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

The output of all of them is:

```
'TheraininSpainstaysmainlyintheplain'
```